# How do I retrieve * literal using read command?

Tags: bash

I have a script that receives input from the user. One of the possible values I want to retrieve is  the literal `*`. It seems the shell is intercepting it and executing so that I'm getting a list of all the file names.

```
while   read -p "Enter operand: " operandTwo
        echo "Argument: $operandTwo"           
        echo "Argument: $(echo $operandTwo)"
        [ $operandTwo != X ]
        echo "Result: $?"
do...
```

This is the output:

```
Argument: *
Argument: File1 File2 File3
./script: line 20: [: too many arguments
Result: 2
```

Is the comparison being made here between `File1 File2 File3` and `X`? How do I make a comparison between `*` and `X` instead?

Comment: Run your script through https://shellcheck.net and follow its advice.

Comment: tldr `$(echo $operandTwo)` is redundant and the variable expansion should be quoted